Can't built and run QT project with Xcode
I built my QT app on macOS Sonoma with QT 6.7.0 and QT Creator 13 for iOS and was able to run it from QT Creator on iPhone Simulator.
Then I opened generated .xcodeproj file in Xcode, but "Run Active Scheme" button is disabled:

While my app is selected as active scheme:

"Run" and "Build" items in "Project" menu are also disabled:

With previous versions Xcode and QT Creator I was able to build and run a QT project in this way.
What changed?

It is because I moved build directory. It probably works with absolute paths.
